# T-SQL Pivot with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I know there's a ton of Pivot questions, but every one I find seems to do some sort of SUM or COUNT operation, which is not what I need. I have a table like this:

```
id      field        val
---------------------------------
1234    type         Blade Server
1234    memory       24
1234    hostname     test_box1
4567    type         Blade Server
4567    memory       98
4567    hostname     test_box2
4567    ip           192.168.1.4
```

id is a foreign key that links field/val. What is in field is dynamic and not known ahead of time... it's basically a generic key/value pair store. (Which I can't change BTW... it's already set in the architecture). But I'm trying to create a pivot view that will take the above table and give me this:

```
id      type            memory  hostname    ip  
-------------------------------------------------------
1234    Blade Server    24      test_box1   NULL
4567    Blade Server    98      test_box2   192.168.1.4
```

Note that id 1234 does not have an "ip" field entry, so it needs to show up as NULL in the pivoted table. Basically, every "field" option should become a column, linked by "id". I guess this is an aggregation operation, but I couldn't figure how to make it work...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like a basic dinamic pivot. Did you try use `MAX()` or `MIN()` as your aggregation function?

Comment: MAX/MIN on what column?

Comment: Although you didn't tag the question with sql-server I assumed it was as the title had t-sql in it. The question I marked as duplicate should help you. Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: what is your rdbms sql server, oracle, mysql?

Comment: @jpw I think he need a dynamic pivot

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes indeed, and that is exactly what the duplicate deals with (as well as the second question I linked to).

Comment: @jpw, my bad the screen only show first half of the answer and was a static pivot.

Comment: Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ca9c7/7) of your sample working in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza , that worked! Slightly more complicated since the table I was using was actually a join of two other tables... I left that part out... but I made a temp table and it works fine with that :)